# Google Cloud Monitoring MQL: Time of Day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

Is it possible to use MQL to include time of day in the alert condition?

Basic example in their documentation includes:

```
  fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time
  | rate (5m)
  | condition lt(val(), 0.5's{CPU}/min')
```

I essentially want to do this:

```
  fetch gce_instance :: compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time
  | rate (5m)
  | condition lt(val(), 0.5's{CPU}/min') and ( gt(end.time, '06:00:00') and lt(end.time, '18:00:00') )
```

Obviously that isn't valid, but I'm struggling to put the syntax together for time related functions from their documentation - does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: An alerting policy that uses MQL can have only the single MQL-based condition. Policies with multiple conditions are not supported if a condition uses MQL.
This is mentioned in [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#mql-policy-api) and refer to this link for [time formats](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-language?hl=en#ql-dates) and sample [alert policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#ql-alert-condition)

Comment: please review above comment and Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also want this so I can silence alerts during scheduled nightly upgrades. I could not find a way to do it with MQL, but here are some workarounds that might help:

1. **Create a [snooze](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/snooze)**. You can select a period of time over which the alert will be silenced. Due to its [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/snooze#restrictions) it only works if your quiet period is rare:

   - You can only create them with the console
   - There is no "recurring snooze," so if you want a daily quiet period then you have to create a snooze every day using the console
2. Create a [cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) job to **enable and disable the alert using the [alerting API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-enable-policy)**.

I am trying the **API** approach. The enable/disable calls can be made from my upgrade job, so I don't think I need the scheduler. Here are the steps I used to work this out:

1. List the monitoring policies to get the policy name. Note conditions have names too. You want the policy name, **not the condition name**:

   ```
   gcloud alpha monitoring policies list
   ```
2. Disable/enable the policy:

   ```
   gcloud alpha monitoring policies update projects/<project-name>/alertPolicies/<policy-id> --no-enabled
   # Do my upgrade...
   gcloud alpha monitoring policies update projects/<project-name>/alertPolicies/<policy-id> --enabled
   ```

Comment: I love the idea of using Cloud Scheduler to enable/disable the alerting policy on a schedule... Great idea, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This produces a metric that indicates when a vm instance is up but only during interesting times of day:

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| filter (metric.instance_name == 'foo')
| align rate(1m)
| filter (timestamp_to_string(end(), '%H:%M') >= '13:30')
| filter (timestamp_to_string(end(), '%H:%M') < '20:00')
...
```